# How to filter isnull False value in Django-filters?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to only filter category which has `channels__livestream__isnull=False`. The Queryset is working fine with this paremter but the `Django-filters` getting error `TypeError: 'FilterSetMetaclass' object is not iterable`.

filters.py

```py
class CategoryFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):

    has_live_stream = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        field_name='channels__livestream',
        lookup_expr='isnull',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = YTCategory
        fields = ['has_live_stream']
```

views.py

```py
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    queryset = YTCategory.objects.active()
    pagination_class = Pagination
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = CategoryFilterSet
    search_fields = ['id', 'name']
```

Comment: My guess is that `filterset_fields` needs to be iterable. `filterset_fields = CategoryFilterSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs for django-rest-framework (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#overriding-the-initial-queryset) it looks like you should be setting `filterset_class` instead of `filterset_fields` in your views.py:

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    queryset = YTCategory.objects.active()
    pagination_class = Pagination
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter] 
    filterset_class = CategoryFilterSet # Changed from filterset_fields
    search_fields = ['id', 'name']
```